# Is there another way to use vlookup to decide which results based on further criteria?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a VLOOKUP-based [Lookup Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4jrD.png) which references a [Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO3QE.png) to pull its values.
In essence, when a few hostnames are pasted in the Lookup Table, the Zone and Owner are populated.
My issue, in this example, is a situation where a hostname in the Data table is listed more than once. Specifically, as you can see looking up "Alpha8" returns North and Jeff, since it is the 1st occurrence in the data table.

Now look at the actual data table... there are 3 rows that have Alpha8 listed. How can I have the Lookup Table (VLOOKUP formula) return row 10 instead of the first occurrence, row 9? For example I'd like my VLOOKUP to basically say "if duplicate value is found, return the row that has 'west' in the 'Zone' column.

I know there are some work-around ways to address this for smaller subsets of data like in my example here, but I'm looking for something that would work if the data table had several thousand entries (with many duplicates) and the values being "searched" in the lookup table were maybe a few hundred.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think that what you're looking is not possible with VLOOKUP, I have here a solution using an array formula with INDEX:

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$8,MAX(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,$E3)>1,($B$1:$B$8="west"),1)*($A$1:$A$8=$E3)*ROW($A$1:$A$8)))
```

[image]

See the brackets at the beginning and the end of the formula, that's because is an array formula, so you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to works as expected.

I let you the example here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eXiMBGTjLr-VxKWW_UWGO9EHAXF3spuu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I did expect that my answer would rely in the index function and not within vlookup, so thank you for figuring out a way to solve using index. That said, I imagine in practice my formulas would be very long to accomodate for the various other scenarios. For example, I'll truly be matching against 3 other column's data, not just one. I think there should be a more native way to do this in excel, this is becoming over complicated unforunately! Thank you, though!

Comment: Have you consider to use a helper column?